# Why is my unit testing is not working?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing

I'm using vs17, Whenever I run any of the tests I get this

> [4/5/2018 12:10:19 PM Informational] ------ Run test started ------
>   [4/5/2018 12:10:19 PM Warning] [MSTest][Discovery][C:*path*\bin\Debug\FeatureFlags.API.Tests.dll] The given assembly name or codebase was invalid. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131047)
>   [4/5/2018 12:10:19 PM Warning] No test is available in C:*path*\bin\Debug\FeatureFlags.API.Tests.dll. Make sure that test discoverer & executors are registered and platform & framework version settings are appropriate and try again.
>   [4/5/2018 12:10:19 PM Informational] ========== Run test finished: 0 run (0:00:00.7650001) ==========

I feel the need to ensure that I have searched for this problem in tons of other questions and other sites and non of the solutions solve my problem, and most of them is either very old questions or for vs15 before update 2 where it solves the problem or prior to framework 4.6 and I'm currently using framework 4.7. and I can't downgrade my framework version.

I've added a .runsettings file, used debugging " it never hits the break points or even start to run anything", I have changed the default processor architecture, and I've disabled "Enable just my code", none of that worked for me. I rebuilt the solution a lot of times and even did closed the visual studio and restarted my pc.

In the debugging mode, I can see in the output windows

> "Cannot find or open the PDB file"

a lot of times for different files.

What is my mistake and how to solve this?

**EDIT 1**
here is an example of my test cases

```
[TestClass]
public class VezeetaFeatureFlagsTests
{
    private readonly FeatureFlagController _controller;

    public VezeetaFeatureFlagsTests()
    {
        MockHttpContext();
        _controller = new FeatureFlagController(new FeatureFlagCore(new FeatureFlagDAL(new RedisClient("FeatureFlags.RedisConnectionString"))));
    }

    private void MockHttpContext()
    {
        HttpContext.Current = new HttpContext(
            new HttpRequest("", "http://localhost:2812/", ""),
            new HttpResponse(new StringWriter())
        );

        Path.Combine(@"*Path*", "");

    }

[TestMethod]
    public void Valid_AddKey()
    {
        List<AddTagsAndFeaturesModel> addTagsAndFeaturesModels = new List<AddTagsAndFeaturesModel>
        {
            new AddTagsAndFeaturesModel()
            {
                Key = "test",
                Values = new List<object>()
            {
                "Feature 1",
                "Feature 2"
            },
                IsHide = false,
                IsTags = false
            }
        };

        var result = _controller.AddFeaturesOrTags(addTagsAndFeaturesModels);

        Assert.AreEqual(result.StatusCode, HttpStatusCode.OK);

    }
```

}
and I can see it in the test explorer.

Comment: You need to show your code in your question. We need to see the signatures of the methods and the classes they're in, and any attributes applied to them. In other words, make a [MCVE].

Comment: Did you add the class I asked you about? You also need to describe what unit test library you're using and what unit test runner extensions you have installed.

Comment: @mason If I get this right, I'm using a visual studio Unit Test Project(.Net Framework) , and for the extensions I'm using (Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework & Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.Extensions)
is that what you mean?

Comment: Please make sure you've cleaned out Visual Studio's runner cache. If it gets corrupted, Visual Studio will permanently misbehave until it's deleted. To clear the cache, shut down all instances of Visual Studio, then delete the folder %TEMP%\VisualStudioTestExplorerExtensions (honestly, it probably wouldn't hurt to delete everything in %TEMP% that can be deleted).

Comment: @DanWilson Thank you for the tip, I did delete the mentioned folder after closing all vs instances, reopened and the issue still there.

Comment: Well, that worked for me in the past. I've got nothing left. Create a new solution, write a new unit test, and see if you can run *any* tests at all.

Comment: @DanWilson yeah I thought about that, I even did removed .Tests project and added a new one, but unfortunate it didn't work, so I've thought about changing the entire solution if none worked.

Comment: Is there something awry in your app.settings or references to your main project dlls from you test project not valid?